# Firebase Analytics: Manually return a user's audiences

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I want to write a firebase cloud function that returns a value based on the analytics audiences the user belongs to.  To that end I need a way, either on the front end or the backend, to manually query what audiences a given user belongs to.  Is there any way to do this in firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is currently possible.

Audiences are used to :

- [Filter reports](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317500) so you can analyze how different user segments engage with your app
- Target Notifications to individual audiences
- Target [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) to deliver custom experiences to different audiences

In the case of reports you can add a filter based on single user property such as age or gender but not for an specific user.